# Couldn't connect to postgres instance

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I made a nodejs app and now I want to deploy it to Google Cloud but I couldn't make it connect to PostgresQL successfully. My deployed app and the Postgres instance run on the same project and I use this connection string:

```
pg://postgres:[password]@/[db_name]?host=/cloudsql/[Instance_name_of_Postgres]
```

but every time I try to make a request, Knex always return this message:

> Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?

While in my development machine, I allow the IP address and connect to the Postgres instance using that connection string with the server ip with any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string is incorrect, it is not `@/[db_name]?host`, it is `@host/db_name`.

The full syntax supported by the driver is:

```
postgres://username:password@host:port/database?ssl=false&application_name=name
&fallback_application_name=name&client_encoding=encoding
```

Comment: My config is right, I followed the tutorial on gcloud site though. I figured out the problem is that I didn't enable the SQL service. Still thank you for the answer